# for loop to change the value of arguments of a built in function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a for loop that use a built-in function, changing the value of one of its arguments at every run.

The built-in function is qmatrix.mns from msm package (multi-stage-Markov models). It calculates transition rates amongst different stages. Its main arguments are: a multistage Markov model (msm.Full) and covariates (provided in a list).

I wrote the following function (it worked):

```
transRate<-function(grossTon,held, cpue){
  estim<-data.frame(matrix(rep(0,21),7,3))  
  for(i in 1:3){  
    qMatrix<-qmatrix.msm(msm.Full,  ci="normal", covariates=list(grossTon=grossTon,    held=held, cpue=cpue,period=i))

          estim[i]<-qMatrix$estimates[c(5,2,10,7,13,14,15)]# extracts transition rates that I'm interested in
          rownames(estim)<-c("q12","q21","q23","q32","q14","q24","q34")
          colnames(estim)<-c("period 1", "period 2","period 3")
        }

          return(estim)                     
    }                    

    transRate(grossTon=10,held=10,cpue=0.5)
```

the result was:

```
    period1     period2     period3
q12 0.011523315 0.01100657  0.01051299
q21 0.006939337 0.00528312  0.004022193
q23 0.161752987 0.079884    0.039451841
q32 0.016379169 0.01661803  0.01686038
q14 1.134517831 1.13026321  1.126024543
q24 0.426243172 0.78585263  1.448854529
q34 0.240552571 0.74682982  2.318639844
```

It was easy, because the covariate "period" has 3 possible values: 1, 2, 3, but the story was different when I tried with the covariate "grossTon", whose potential values are between 10 and 120. What I want to is that grossTon takes values 10, 20, 30, ...,120.

Please have a look at what I did:

```
transRate<-function(held, cpue, period){
estim<-data.frame(matrix(rep(0,84),7,12)) 
grossT<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120)
  for(i in grossT){  #I guess the problem is here
    qMatrix<-qmatrix.msm(msm.Full,  ci="normal", covariates=list(grossTon=i, held=held, cpue=cpue,period=period))
    estim[i]<-qMatrix$estimates[c(5,2,10,7,13,14,15)]
    rownames(estim)<-c("q12","q21","q23","q32","q14","q24","q34")
    colnames(estim)<-c("10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100","110","120")

   }
    return(estim)                     
}                    

transRate(held=10,cpue=0.5,period=1)
```

What I'm expecting is the following output:

```
    10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120
q12                                             
q21                                             
q23                                             
q32                                             
q14                                             
q24                                             
q34
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a loop over any desired vector.  Thus:

```
for (i in seq(10,120,by=10))
```

is one way to go about it.  You could, in the general case, do

```
for (i in c(10,15,23,50,100,273))
```

or whatever values you need.